# Action not called when attached to context MenuItem (and when it hidden)

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have action with registered accelerator key for it

```
  public Rotate180Action() {
    putValue(NAME, "180");
    putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_R, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK));
  }
```

this action attached to Context menu (not a top menu or other)

```
  private JMenu buildRotateSubMenu() {
    rotateSubMenu.add(new JMenuItem(rotateLeft90Action));
    rotateSubMenu.add(new JMenuItem(rotateRight90Action));
    rotateSubMenu.add(new JMenuItem(rotate180Action));
    return rotateSubMenu;
  }
```

So, the problem is that action called by "Ctrl+R" when context menu is visible on screen, but not called when context menu is not showed

thanks for your help!

Comment: If a menu is not visible then the binding are removed. You will need to add the key bindings manually. This is why it is always better to display the menu with the Actions. This also serves as a form of self documentation.

Comment: camickr, thanks for your reply. How can I flag that I accepted your reply as correct?

Comment: You can only accept answers. Your above comment will indicate that my comment solved your problem. Thanks for replying.